# Chrome doesn't save my session history?

Tags: google-chrome

This is something that's been bugging me for a while. When I used Firefox in the past I was able to restore my previous session; with an add-on; the individual tab history was intact, and I could press back previous pages.

But with chrome I have tried all the session extensions out there and it only save the links (as if I bookmarked them) I want to restore my session with its tab history. How?  I'd really appreciate it if there's an actual solution to this, because Google didn't help one bit.

Comment: Google Chrome should do this with a normal session.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to restore the session  history of the Google chrome so that it would always come  with the history you have previously browsed.

We request you to follow the below steps

(i)Open settings tab in the google chrome  and then go to startup menu.

(ii) Now check the option continue from where you left off.

Once you have selected.Then the chrome would  open the tab previously opened